# Netbeans 7.0 + Zend Framework + Dojo

Tags: zend-framework, netbeans, dojo

I'm starting to develop a basic web application with Zend Framework using Netbeans 7.
I don't get suggestions from the IDE when writing $this->dojo()-> ....

How can I enable suggestions?

Am I missing something? Was I supposed to do something in particular to enable suggestions (eg. include some dojo paths, etc..)?

I looked into Zend docs, but I didn't find anything about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add Zend library + ZendX library into the projects PHP include path (`Project properties/PHP Include path`) or in `Options/PHP/General/Global Include path`

However many of the suggestions wont appear, because large part of the framework depend on magic functions and context which Netbeans cannot track

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use PhpStorm!
http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/
In my opinion is the best IDE around!